# JasperReports Server: Chart Theme without Java knowledge

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I found some older (outdated) solutions extending a special Java class to build a new theme.
I am using Jasper without Java knowledge and wonder if (since version 5.3 of the server is out) there is an easier way of applying new colors to the charts.

Is there a ResourceDescriptor able to hol a color theme?
Like the properties' one?

I use the REST (2) API, but no Java at all. Did possibilities change now in the last 4 years?

Basically I want to use the aegean theme but apply some different colors.